# getting error when covert dataframe to sqlite in python

Tags: python

I am trying covert excel data to Sqlite.

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('D:\\New folder\\TDS_DB_Reco\\Temp\\Test.xlsx')
conn = sqlite3.connect('TDSTest_database.db')

c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("create table if not exists Mastercode ({})".format(','.join(dfs.columns)))

for i in dfs.iterrows():
    sql='Insert into Mastercode ({}) values ({})'.format(','.join(dfs.columns),','.join(['?']*len(dfs.columns)))
    c.execute(sql,tuple(i[1]))
conn.commit()
dfs.shape
```

I am getting error of File

```
"D:/New folder/TDS_DB_Reco/26AS_temp.py", line 30, in <module> c.execute(sql,tuple(i[1]))   
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is your error

Comment: i am trying covert excel data to Sqlite.

Comment: and i m getting error of
  File "D:/New folder/TDS_DB_Reco/26AS_temp.py", line 30, in <module>
    c.execute(sql,tuple(i[1]))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Can you add your `.xlsx` file also

Comment: Your fist binding parameter is probably of unsupported type.

Comment: yes i have screen shot of this xlsx file

Comment: I think that error is Date type not support